# How to debug a DirectX crash on client machine?

Tags: directx, debugging

I have customers who are experiencing crashes which I can't reproduce on my machine.

From the minidumps they sent over, it appears that their crashes all seem to be in unexplained Direct3D calls, deep in the callstack in d3d11.dll.

How can I debug this problem? Is there any way to log client d3d error messages? I can't use the debug layer since they don't have the DirectX SDK, right?

Comment: What OS are they using? If you enable Microsoft Symbol Server then your minidump should provide a detailed callstack. You should also confirm that your application generates no ERROR or CORRUPTION messages on your development machine.

Answer (score 1):

I still haven't been able to figure out precisely what's happening on client machines (despite having good minidumps with symbols).

I'm posting an answer to whichever poor souls might be having this similar problem. In my case the users' crashes were caused / exposed by overlay software. This includes the Steam Overlay, and a program called OverWolf. Disabling those programs "fixed" the problem.

Again, no idea what the presumed root of the issue is. I only have that workaround.

Comment: Investigate the code around your swap-chain presentation. That's how those overlays work, they inject some code every time you swap buffers.